# Classes in javascript and scopes of members

Tags: javascript

Jumping to code first:

```
function myClass(arg1,arg2){
    this.arg1=arg1;
    this.arg2=arg2;
}

myClass.prototype.sayArg=function(){
    console.log("First Arg is "+ arg1);
}
```

1. Why do i have to add 'prototype' to declare a function for the class? Even if it would get extend, should every child would not get this method by default? What is it actually , i am juggling 'class' and 'prototype' from starting.I read this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_JavaScript_Framework) , couldnt understand yet :(
2. If i define my class with that literary(or just a '=new Object()' ) method , how can i define a constructor later , so that i could use

   ```
   var anObject=new myClass(arg1,arg2);
   ```
3. If you notice , i havent used 'this.arg' in 6th line , and it is an error, which brings me to my last doubt. I am already specifying 'myClass.' means it belongs to myClass , still, it isn't able to access its 'arg1' member? Why i have to use 'this.' to acess it while it is in same class? Is it knid of private member? But as the function belongs to same class , it should get access to it ( kind of in c++ ).

Thanks :)

Comment: There really is no such thing as a "Class" in JavaScript. Inheritance in JavaScript is much different than inheritance in other common languages like Java and C++.

Comment: You're asking the most fundamental questions of prototypal inheritance. What you should do is read some instructional material. There's no shortage of information on the topic.

Comment: @Pointy , classes arent there in javascript? So there are objects , but no classes? What are objects of then( I mean their blueprint)?

Comment: @cookiemonster , any links , pointers or directions that would help me :)

Comment: Well, I suppose I could link to StackOverflow. You'll find lots of Q & A here. Also plenty of resources are listed here under the JavaScript tag wiki. MDN is also a good resource. And then there's Google of course.

Comment: Objects are just key-value stores. I mean, they have some additional, mostly internal behavior, but essentially they are just kv stores. http://es5.github.io/#x8.6

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal there are facilities that provide functionality that is similar to the functionality you get from class-based inheritance systems like C++, but they are different in some very basic ways.

Comment: Maybe the following answer can help you understand what prototype is and how JavaScript determines what this is. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941 maybe check out mdn as well how JavaScript scope works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to build a mental model of how Javascript objects are implemented: if you're coming from a C++ background then consider this possible model

### All objects in javascript are of the same class, the class "Object"

Each object is defined with something like

```
class Object {
    std::map<std::string, Object *> attributes;
};
```

and this means for example that

1. The set of attributes is not fixed, you can add attributes at runtime to a specific object instance
2. Inheritance doesn't work like in C++

### Each object has a special attribute named `constructor`

The `constructor` of an object is the function that was used to instantiate the object. For example if you write

```
function Person(first_name, last_name) {
    this.first_name = first_name;
    this.last_name = last_name;
}
```

then executing

```
var p = new Person("Andrea", "Griffini");
alert(p.constructor === Person);
```

Will display "true" in a message box.

### The constructor is an object too

The `constructor` of the `constructor` is `Function`, and as you probably guess it's an object too, with itself as constructor.

### A constructor has a special attribute named `prototype`

This special attribute is what allows inheritance among other things. The rules followed by Javascript are simple: when accessing a attribute `attr` of an object `x`

1. if the instance `x` has itself the requested attribute then the value is returned
2. otherwise `x.constructor.prototype` is looked up for `attr` instead of `x`

The second step is also recursive, meaning that if `x.constructor.prototype` doesn't have the attribute either then `x.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype` is searched instead and so on.

When **setting** an attribute however Javascript simply sets it in the instance, not following the `constructor.prototype` chain.

This explains the apparently strange behavior...

```
function Person(first_name, last_name) {
    this.first_name = first_name;
    this.last_name = last_name;
}

Person.prototype.display = function() {
    return this.first_name + ", " + this.last_name;
}

var p = new Person("Andrea", "Griffini");
var q = new Person("John", "Smith");

q.display = function() {
    return "... not sure ...";
}

alert(p.display()); // Says "Andrea, Griffini"
alert(q.display()); // Says "... not sure ..."
```

### `this` is a run-time concept in Javascript

`this` can be seen simply as a global variable that is automatically set by Javascript: more specifically when you write

```
obj.method(...);
```

the `method` attribute is looked up as usual, but before being called `this` is set to `obj` and restored to its current value once the method returns; in other words what happens is more or less:

```
// Not real code, just to show the concept
var old_this = this;
this = obj;
method(...);
this = old_this;
```

and it also means that the two fragments

```
// First case
var f = obj.method;
f();

// Second case
obj.method();
```

are **not** equivalent, because in the first case the code of the method will be executed with `this` being "the global object", while in the second case `this` value will be `obj` during the execution of the method code. The `this` magic only happens if you call the result of an attribute lookup... even just using `[obj.method][0]()` is not the same as `obj.method()` because `this` will be the array (that has been looked up for the attribute `0`) during the execution of method code.

## This is not the whole truth

This reply only wants to give you a rough description of how things more or less are working in Javascript and of course they're not the truth but I think just these few ideas should be able to take you far enough into Javascript programming.

For the whole truth you'd need to read quite a bit more.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript has no classes, just objects...

> "One of the key differences is that JavaScript does not have classes;
>   instead, the class functionality is accomplished by object
>   prototypes."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Objects

[I recommend you read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript)... it's probably the best introduction to JavaScript I've seen.  It's not a big read, won't take you long and should help answer all your questions.